# Give both an exact and asymptotic answer for the pseudo code below

Tags: time, asymptotic-complexity, exact-match

```
for i <--- 1 step i <--- 2* i while i< n do 
  for j <--- 1 step j <---2* j while j<n do 
    if j = 2*i 
      for k = 0 step k <--- k+ 1 while k < n do 
        .... CONSTANT NUMBER OF ELEMENTARY OPERATIONS 
      end for 
    else 
      for k<--- 1 step k<-- 3*k while k<n do 
        ...CONSTANT NUBER OF ELEMENTARY OPERATIONS 
      end for 
    end if 
  end for 
end for
```

What is the running time for the following code fragment as a function of n?

The 'exact answer' refers to the equation relating to the code BEFORE you determine the asymptotic running time.

Comment: To get an exact answer, you should ask an exact question first...

Comment: What is the running time for the following code fragment as a function of n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as homework, however, making a few considerations, the asymptotic complexity of that pseudo code should be `O(n*log(n))`.

You cannot estimate exactly the running time since it highly depends on your system.

Comment: Its not homework. Its an exercise from a book. I get a different answer thats why. The book has no answers so I dont know how to double check myself. I actually got a different answer and cheers for that. I will practise more these but sometimes I getconfused between asymptotic and exact answer. Would you be kind enough to explain the difference.